# php json encode not encoding array

Tags: php, json

i have php array like ((  print_r($fdata); ))

```
Array
(
    [status] => YES
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Need
                            [1] => Am need
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => No deductibles and no copayments.
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => No lifetime limit—policy won't terminate based on number or dollar amount of claims paid.
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Volvo
                            [1] => 22
                            [2] => 18
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Volvo
                            [1] => 22
                            [2] => 18
                        )
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Volvo
                            [1] => 22
                            [2] => 18
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Volvo
                            [1] => 22
                            [2] => 18
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

i want to encode it to json , but when i pass it to "json_encode" function it print blank result ! 
about my php code 
i have declared few php array in which i load data from database

```
$fdata = array();   // final data to process
$product = array();  // product info
$adv_arr = array();  // advantages
$benefits_arr = array();  // benefits
$limits_arr = array();  // limits
$terms_arr = array();  // terms
```

after loading to arrays , i push them to one another array like

```
  $ffdata = array();
  array_push($ffdata , $product ,$adv_arr,$benefits_arr,$terms_arr);
```

and then it end i try to encode but no result

```
  $fdata['status'] = "YES";
              $fdata['data'] = $ffdata;
     echo json_encode($fdata);
```

am trying to produce json data result like :: http://s1.postimg.org/efvvx74xr/C29_CA6_EA8_CAA946_E44076_CA72_B98502932_BA2_A6_DE4517_FB.jpg

sample data :: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/58c5d154

Comment: try to print $fdata using print_r($fdata) and check if it is empty or not.

Comment: above array which i printed is actually $fdata   , which mean its not empty

Comment: try to do print_r(json_encode($fdata));

Comment: try after removing this string `limit—policy won't`

Comment: ya special character was causing problem -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) encounters an error when encoding a data set, it returns `false`, which will not `echo`.

In order to determine if the operation was erroneous, you can use [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to determine what went wrong.

For example:

```php
$json = json_encode($data);

if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    throw new RuntimeException(json_last_error_msg());
}
```

This should provide some more meaningful information if something goes wrong.

At this point, if you are getting a WSOD instead of any output then you might have a different problem; e.g: a fatal or parse error. In this case you should ensure that error reporting is *enabled* while developing (and, crucially, ensure it's *disabled* in your production environment!).

Generally, the easiest way to do this is to add the following to the top of your script:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi. Look at the [JSON error codes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). 5 represents `JSON_ERROR_UTF8 `. it looks like you have malformed UTF8 data. For a more meaningful, human-readable error message use `echo json_last_error_msg();`.

Comment: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded' in line #

Comment: Indeed. You need to look at your data, that's where the problem is. Are you extracting it from a database or somewhere else? If you want to update your question to provide an example of this data we might be able to debug further. At the moment we can only determine the why there's a problem, not what :)

Comment: looks like json cant encode special characters like —